# DAG: causal direction unknown

Tags: causality, dag

I have a DAG as follows. Interested in the direct effect of E on O. Plus interested in publishing an article with a sound methodology.

There definitely (read: highly probably) is a causal direction between E and V; however, we do not know the direction (impossible to define). But we assume a correlation between V and E, meaning that if V is high, less E is needed for higher O. And vice versa. Therefore, we mark V as "adjusted" in DAGitty.

**1. Is such approach correct?**

**2. How should I name a DAG without a known direction - just causal graph?**

**3. How should I present "an unknown direction relationship" on that figure? A line without arrow heads?**

[image]